# Can I make \ref{} to say where the referenced thing is (page X, just above, just below)?

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a text with few figures, equations and text. Sometimes I reference these figures/equations with `\ref{label}`. I would like to help my readers know where the referenced figure/equation is in the text, so when I mention them, I use `\ref{label} on page \pageref{label}`. Is there a way to issue a command, which behaves something like the examples I give below?

If referenced object is earlier or later, on a different page:

- `\mynewcommand{label}` output: `Figure X on page Y`

If rerenced object is shown earlier, on the same page:

- `\mynewcommand{label}` output: `Figure X, just above`

If rerenced object is later earlier, on the same page:

- `\mynewcommand{label}` output: `Figure X, just below`

How could I achieve this? (Ideally, the solution wouldn't require me to know in advance where the referenced object is going to be placed.)

Comment: There is a package for this but I can't remember its name.

Comment: see the `varioref` package

Comment: Thank you. I am not yet able to come up with a working version, but it seems quite good.